# C# To F# loops to return a value

Tags: c#, f#

How to Write this code in f#

```
 int IAI.AIMove()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
            if (cBoard.getPlayer(i) == 0)
                return i;
        return 0;
    }
```

This is what i have

```
member this.AIMove()=
      let result =  int in
        for i in 1 .. 8 do
            if cboard.getPlayer(i)=0 then
               result := Some i
```

[error] 
This expression was expected to have type     int     but here has type     unit

Comment: Change the == to `result := Some i`, but notice that it will keep on looping and will return the **last** valid `i`.

Comment: nope same error. tried that earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Board =
    member x.getPlayer (i: int) = 0 // Just a stub to allow typechecking

let move (cBoard: Board) =
    let isZero x = x = 0
    let found = seq { 0 .. 8 } |> Seq.tryFind (cBoard.getPlayer >> isZero)
    defaultArg found 0
```

Comment: BTW, why `defaultArg` has that arguments order? It makes it quite unsuitable for partial application...

Comment: Define a `flip` function :)

Comment: @RamonSnir of course, I can, but this is 1 extra step. Or it is already in F#?

Comment: It's in FSharpX (or was, didn't update for a while).

Answer (score 2):

While you can rewrite C# code to F# line-by-line, you will not really get much of the F# elegance in that way. I'd recommend playing with some really simple problems first (like working with lists) and then thinking about how you could design your project to be a bit more functional.

To answer your question, you can use `List.tryFind` instead of loop and mutation:

```
let idx = [ 0 .. 8 ] |> List.tryFind (fun i -> cBoard.getPlayer(i) = 0)
```

This generates a list with numbers from 0 to 1 and then returns first number such that the given predicate returns true. This behaves a bit differently than your code - it returns `option<int>` which is either `None` if a value was not found or `Some(i)` when the value was found.

It is probably a good idea to use options and pattern matching, but you could use `defaultArg idx 0` to return 0 if the value was not found.

Comment: Why use List? There's no need to store all numbers. Better to use `seq { 0 .. 8 }`

Comment: @SargeBorsch Since the OP is apparently learning about F#, I thought I'd use the simplest possible type. Also, for 8 elements, the difference does not really matter. But yes, you're right - using sequence would make more sense.

Comment: this.AIMove () is an implementation of an interface. how can i use you function? plz help

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on keeping your code C#'ish:

```
member this.AIMove () : int option =
  let result = ref None
  for i in 1 .. 8 do
    if cboard.getPlayer(i)=0 then
      result := Some i
  match !result with
  | Some i -> i
  | None -> 0
```

Comment: I funtion must return 0 if nothing is found